# Ionic ios How to implements a barcode and QRCode scanner

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have used [this](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git) plugin for scanner functionality.

In that QRCode works perfectly But Barcode scanner is not working.

Comment: What kind of barcode? Which platform? Please note, that not every kind is supported and there is a platform dependency -> refer https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner

Comment: i have develope my application in ionic framework. In that a have used plugin which is mentioned above. Now Exactly what happen In Android Barcode and QRCode scanning is run perfectly. But in ios QRcode run perfectly and Barcode scanning not working. Please help me out. m in trouble.

Comment: This kind of barcode>>>  https://www.google.co.in/search?q=barcode&espv=2&biw=1220&bih=637&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu6qPf1YjNAhWEj5QKHfD9BA8Q_AUIBigB#imgrc=eERSULOTr903WM%3A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note this part of plugin description.

Android

- QR_CODE
- DATA_MATRIX
- UPC_E
- UPC_A
- EAN_8
- EAN_13
- CODE_128
- CODE_39
- CODE_93
- CODABAR
- ITF
- RSS14
- PDF417
- RSS_EXPANDED

iOS

- QR_CODE
- DATA_MATRIX
- UPC_E
- UPC_A
- EAN_8
- EAN_13
- CODE_128
- CODE_39
- ITF

Your EAN_13 code is supported of both platforms. And I have tried to scan your code with my Iphone. In my case it works only if I put the code on a white background. I wasn't able to scan the code in the google view presenting the code with a darkgrey border.

Comment: mine sample barcode is type of EAN_13?? How can u identify? I only understand thta sample is of EAN type. And What is the solution for scannig problem??? can u help me out ? Thanks in advance buddy

Comment: Because it contains 13 numbers ;-)

Comment: Try to copy the image and paste in your word and then scan again

Comment: Have u any other solution for that?

Comment: hey, @Simon Schüpbach, Help me